# Start BroadCastReceiver From Activity

Tags: android

I want to start a `BroadcastReceiver` from an `Activity`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define your BroadcastReceiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver             receiver
    = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Register your receiver in onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Unregister the receiver in onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Comment: Hi Erich i think u can undersstood my problem please refer link below and if u can responce on the same place..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295724/unable-to-send-broadcast-from-activity-to-other-android