# How to close this activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-manifest

I created my lockscreen application that trigerred by a SMS.. i have ListenSMS class that always listen for incoming SMS. Here's the code :

```
for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
    String tempMessage[] = message.getDisplayMessageBody().toString().split(" ");

    //checking command dan password                             
    if (tempMessage[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("andro-lock") && tempMessage[1].toString().equals(tempPassword.toString())) {
        //Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this, "Menjalankan command andro-lock", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        openDatabase();
        updateStatusL();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListenSMSservice.this,LockScreenForm.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    else if (tempMessage[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("andro-unlock") && tempMessage[1].toString().equals(tempPassword.toString())) {
        //Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this, "Menjalankan command andro-unlock", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        openDatabase();
        updateStatusNL();                                                                   
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListenSMSservice.this,LockScreenForm.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle myKillerBundle = new Bundle();
        myKillerBundle.putString("kill","1");
        myIntent.putExtras(myKillerBundle);
        getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

If ListenSMS service has received an `andro-lock` command, it will go to the `lockscreen.java`  and will go to the lockscreen.java with intent extra (putExtra) `kill` when it receive command `andro-unclock`. **Here's my lockscreen.java:**

```
public class LockScreenForm extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);             

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, extra.getString("kill"), 1).show();
        else if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("kill").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this, "extra accepted", 1).show();
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I want to close my locksreen.java when my `ListenSMS` service has received "andro-unlock" command, so I put extra on intent "kill" and check it in lockscreen.java. This lockscreen.java can check the extra intent and can display a toast "extra accepted" but can close the lockscreen activity with finish().

My assumption is for now that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is duplicating a locksreen activity. So it will create a double lockscreen activity and the finish method is closing another lockscreen.java that started by `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. That's only assumption. Am i wrong? Please correct me.

Has anyone know how to solve my problem? I really want that "andro-unlock" command can close the lockscreen activity and need it works for my college final project. Please help.

Comment: Have a look on it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841544/how-to-finish-activity-from-service-class-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK:

```
When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in. See FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK for a flag to disable this behavior.
```

I expect your problem is somewhere else. I'd suggest having the lockscreen Activity register a BroadcastReceiver, and then when the unlock message is received send an Intent that the BroadcastReceiver will catch. The Activity can then cleanly exit.

Comment: sorry i can't understand your suggestion because i'm still newbie in android.. do you know how to close activity from service?? thanks

Comment: To close an Activity you need to send it a signal of some kind. The easiest signal is an Intent. You can register a BroadcastReceiver as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794776/start-broadcastreceiver-from-activity, and then just fire a matching Intent.

Comment: i was make an intent signal in listenSMS service.. i was put extra intent ("kill") and read them in lockscreen.java..  lockscreen.java have been receive the signal and it can display a toast "extra accepted" but can't run a finish() method?? do you know why?? it's really confused here.. thanks..

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`