# Kill app completely from service class

Tags: android, service, foreground

I have an audio streaming app playing in background`and also a foreground service which should control media player from the background. There is a`CLOSE` button in the foreground which is expected to kill the app completely when clicked.
However, the methods i have used to accomplish that has not yet worked as expected.

```
   public void showNotification() {
            Intent playPauseIntent = new Intent(this, AudioService.class);
            playPauseIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_STREAM_PLAY_PAUSE);

            PendingIntent playPausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    this, 0, playPauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

            Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(this, AudioService.class);
            deleteIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_STOP_RADIO_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent pendingDelete = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                    0,
                    deleteIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
            );
    }

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case Constants.ACTION_STOP_RADIO_SERVICE:
                    hideNotification();
                    stopSelf();
                   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                   this.onDestroy();
// not working as expected. i want app killed from here
                    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to finish activity from service class in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841544/how-to-finish-activity-from-service-class-in-android)

Comment: use binder broadcast recivers.

Comment: generally its bad idea to kill process from service. instead use event bus or broadcast receiver to receive this close event on your main activity.. and then finish it properly.

Comment: @Palak, i solved my problem by sending an intent message to my Main Activity and calling finish() from new Intent method on my Main Activity

Comment: BroadcastReceiver will be the best bet here! :)