# How to unregisterReceiver from an activity

Tags: java, android

I start a service from activity button click that fire a service class and start Broadcastreceiver and it's run in background but I want to unregisterReceiver with a button click from same activity class.it seem not working.I added receiver class to menifest.
Here is my code.

Activity button click for registerreceiver

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent svc = new Intent(this, DemoService.class);
        startService(svc);
    });
```

DemoService.class

```
public class DemoService extends Service {
   static final String LOGGING_TAG = "MyDemo";
   private static Alarm1 tickReceiver =new Alarm1();

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
       Log.v(LOGGING_TAG, "DemoService.onStart()");
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();
       Log.d(LOGGING_TAG, "DemoService.onCreate()");

       registerReceiver(
            new Alarm1(),
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
   }
}
```

Activity button click for unregisterReceiver

```
unreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           DemoService demo=new DemoService();
          demo.unreg();
    });
```

And receiver class

```
public class Alarm1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.d("tag","working");
   }
```

How can I unregisterReceiver from unreg button click.
If I click in unreg button it show me error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:

Comment: if it's locally purpose you should use LocalBroadcastReceiver. Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241128/dynamically-register-unregister-a-broadcast-receiver-in-android 
It may help you

Comment: my app will be run in background.so i can not use onpause method to unregister.@KrzysztofTurek

Comment: could you show me your unreg() method in DemoService? I see that you have tickerReceiver reference, but in onCreate method you create new one
'registerReceiver(
            new Alarm1(), 
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));'

Comment: public void unreg(){this.unregisterReceiver(tickreceiver)} @KrzysztofTurek

Comment: so it can't work because you register "newAlarm1()" instead of register(tickreveiver,...). That's why you see "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:"

Comment: i registerReceiver in onCreate method.see  demoService.class  in unregister it now give me null pointer exception @KrzysztofTurek

Answer (score 1):

> create a method for **unregistering Receiver in Service class**. And call the service with action like.

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, DemoService.class);
 svc.setAction("com.package.UN_REGISTER"); 
 startService(svc);
```

and in `Service` class handle them in `onStartCommand` ()

like

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("com.package.UN_REGISTER")
    //call your unregister method
```

Add action in Manifest in your service Tag

```
<IntentFilter> 
  <action name = "com.package.UN_REGISTER">
</IntentFilter>
```

Comment: hi  if i try to register with button click with your code it give me null pointer exception  my edited code  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        f(intent.getAction().equals("com.package.UN_REGISTER"))
        {
            unreg();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public void unreg() {

        unregisterReceiver(new Alarm1());


    }

Comment: it's now give me illegalargument exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.kotha.bola.ghori.DemoService@4315e990 with Intent { act=com.package.UN_REGISTER cmp=com.kotha.bola.ghori/.DemoService }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.kotha.bola.ghori.Alarm1@4316f Nepster

Comment: Ah at last i figure out what's problem and solve it.i just instantiate receiver class in onStart method in service class.thanks everyone for there effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for this. Check link for implementation and usage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correctly register and unregister a BroadcastReceiver. The BroadcastReceiver passed in registerReceiver() and unregisterReceiver() must be the same instance, so is the Context instance be invoked. Because the implement uses **Context** and **BroadcastReceiver** instances to uniquely map to a "Register operation".