# How can I check whether response is came within one minute after sending SMS in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an application in which I am sending SMS automatically on button click.When SMS is sent I get a response from server in form of SMS.I read that message and perform task on it. Now problem is that when I receive SMS I want to consider only messages received within one minute after button click. What to do.?

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{



    Global mApplication = ((Global)context.getApplicationContext());
    String getPPN=mApplication.getPPN();
    String getStatus=mApplication.getvStatus();
    String ClientId=mApplication.getvClientId();
    String MobileNo=mApplication.getvStrMobile();
    String LocationId=mApplication.getVstrLocation();
    String IMEI=mApplication.getVstrIMEI();

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj .length; i++)
            {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String senderNum = phoneNumber ;



                String message = currentMessage .getDisplayMessageBody();

                mApplication.setvSenderNumber(senderNum);
                mApplication.setvMessageBody(message);
                String IsBroadCast=mApplication.getvAuthenticatedUser();

                try
                {
                    if(IsBroadCast=="1")
                    {
                        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("Message_Recived"));
                    }




                }
                catch(Exception e){}

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

This class is called when SMS received and take me to Arming Activity's on receive method.
But I need that..Broadcast receiver only receive message  only within 1 minute after sendinf SMS

ArmingActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arming);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Message_Recived"));}

 BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // internet lost alert dialog method call from here...
     //   if(strPPN.equals())
        Global globalVariable = (Global) getApplicationContext();
        String vvSenderNumber=globalVariable.getvSenderNumber();
        String vvMessageBody=globalVariable.getvMessageBody();
        String vvPPN=strPPN;
            };

 public void sendSms(String PPN, String smsBody) {

    try {

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(PPN, null, smsBody, null, null);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}




if (strActionText.equals("1")) 
{ 
  sendSms(strPPN, MsgBody);
}
```

Here when send SMS start Broadcast receiver to start receiving SMS for 1 minute.
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the Handler

for that start/register receiver and also start the Handler for the one minute

```
//start your broadcast here.
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // write code to stop/unregister receiver.

        }
    }, 60*1000);
```

for further display time you can use CountDownTimer class.

Comment: how can i do this?I want to start broadcast receiver to receive message withinn 1 minute after sendsms method?

Comment: start broadcast where I commented. and stop broadcast inside run() method. for start http://stackoverflow.com/a/4794872/2900893 this will help you